# Enumerate in equation, labels?

Tags: equations, enumerate

I need a list that is numbered as an equation, and need to refer to the items in the list afterwards but the reference uses the equation number instead.

Minimum example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left. \parbox{.72\linewidth}{\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item \label{list:donec} Donec ac lacus non massa sagittis efficitur a et ante.
\end{enumerate}} \right\}
\end{equation}

I need to refer to item~\ref{list:donec}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any advice regarding the best way to implement this (including the brace) would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am unable to replicate the issue you say you've encountered. Specifically, after I run your test code twice (to resolve all intermediate dependencies), the output of `item~\ref{list:donec}` is "2", not "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have omitted `amsmath` in your minimal example. With this package, there is a stricter control on `\label`s inside a display environment and you need to use the “original” `\label` inside your `enumerate` environment.

I suggest to define a special environment for this, also exploiting `varwidth`, so you don't have to guess a suitable width in case the items are short.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{eqenum}
 {\left.\begin{varwidth}{0.9\displaywidth}\let\label\ltx@label\begin{enumerate}}
 {\end{enumerate}\end{varwidth}\right\}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{eqenum}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  \item \label{list:donec} Donec ac lacus non massa sagittis efficitur a et ante.
\end{eqenum}
\end{equation}

I need to refer to item~\ref{list:donec} and \ref{list:bis}.

\begin{equation}
\begin{eqenum}
  \item \label{list:bis} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  \item Donec ac lacus non massa sagittis efficitur a et ante.
\end{eqenum}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]